# I tried to check probability of some occurrence in sympy stats. Didn't work

Tags: statistics, sympy

I ran this and it is trying to compute for hours. Did I do sth wrong?

```
from sympy import *
from sympy.stats import P
from sympy.stats import Normal

m1,m2,s1,s2 = symbols('\mu_1, \mu_2, \sigma_1, \sigma_2')

x1 = Normal('x_1', m1, s1)
x2 = Normal('x_2', m2, s2)
  
P(x1>x2)
```

Comment: I don't think you're doing anything wrong. That looks like a bug to me. Best to open an issue on github: https://github.com/sympy/sympy/issues

Comment: Just note that giving SymPy as many hints as possible is always good practice. For example `m1,m2 = symbols('\mu_1, \mu_2', real=True)` and `s1,s2 = symbols('\sigma_1, \sigma_2', positive=True)`. It helped a lot with simpler probability statements but sadly not your one.